# Как вывести элементы цикла с задержкой в 1 секунду

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i)
    },1000)
}
```

ответ 3,3,3 почему и как поправить?

Comment: Если просто, то: потому что коллбэк из setTimeout() выполняется спустя 0.999(9) секунды после каждой очередной итерации.

Comment: @0xFFh закройте как дубль

Answer (score 0):

Что бы вывести по порядку, нужно выводить через функцию

```js
$(function() {
  var func = function(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(i)
    }, 1000 * i)
  };
  for(i = 1; i <= 3;i++){
    func(i);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```